# why is only one actionscript working at a time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to Flash and trying to build a very simple game involving moving one movieclip using arrowkeys and avoiding three other movie clips. There is also a start button on the first frame.  Each individual actionscript works by itself as long as the other 4 are commented out. But as soon as I try to use more than one actionscript, none of them work.  I have each actionscript in it's own layer.

I'm sure it's something obvious I'm missing , but how do multiple actionscripts at the same time work?
Any thanks would be greatly appreciated

Here's the code

```
/*Start*/
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClickHandler);
function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}




/*Drive*/
function hearKey(yourEvent:KeyboardEvent):void{
if (yourEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT){
LionOne_mc.x +=  8;
};
if (yourEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT){
LionOne_mc.x -=  8;
};
if (yourEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.UP){
LionOne_mc.y -=  8;
};
if (yourEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN){
LionOne_mc.y +=  8;
};
};
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,hearKey);



/*Colision*/
kangaTwo.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,LionHit2);
function LionHit2(event:Event):void {
if (kangaTwo.hitTestObject(LionOne_mc)) {
tackle_mc.visible = true;
} else {
tackle_mc.visible = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have scripts across multiple layers in a frame. There is no problem with that. They will just run from top most layer, to the bottom.

Although it is technically possible, I would not recommend it. Timeline code is messy at the best of times, so it is best to keep it all in one layer. It is also best practice for this layer to be at the top, with no visual element on it, and for the layer to be named "Actions".

If you are calling `gotoAndStop(2);`, then all the code on frame one will stop running.

When you get the chance you should definitely look at using external ActionScript classes, rather than writing timeline code. There is a great tutorial here: [active.tutsplus.com - AS3 101: OOP Introduction – Basix](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went and did that tutorial today.  Very handy and very similar to the java course I'm also learning at the moment. I'm sure it will come in useful in the future.

Comment: Eventually figured out that the logic behond this was completely wrong. I was having multiple scripts conflicting with true and false statements.